# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn very slow with lots of items

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I have a DataGrid, with several columns. One of them is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. I have a lot of items in this column - more than 1000 - and I need all of them. So grouping is not an option - all items must be there, users must be able to select from all.
The problem is, DataGridViewComboBoxColumn becomes painfully slow, when number of items is about 1000, and above. This issues is well known to Microsoft, it dates back to Visual Studio 2005: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/117024/datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-responds-very-slow-compared-with-the-stand-alone-combobox-control.

The problem is still present in Visual Studio 2010. Any ideas how to solve this?

Is it possible to fill DataGridViewComboBoxColumn with data partially? I mean (that was functionality fully working in Access), when you click DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, some items are displayed (lets say, 100 items). When you scroll down to the latest item, others are loaded (another 100) and so on. I don't see any other option to make DataGridViewComboBoxColumn working faster? Problem is, how to implement this? Has anyone meet that problem before?

Greetings, Frenky

Comment: in general you should avoid loading more than 50 items in a ComboBox, if you have hundreds it's not usable anyway...

Comment: With such huge data, is it possible for you to show it as a dialog form and get the selection (you can choose to show/hide the form) and it could be more convenient as there is large area to glance for choice

Comment: ComboBox works very fine with thousands of items and is very usable. DataGridViewComboBoxColumn is also usable with - lets say - some 800 items. What is above this, becomes painful problem - it is so slow, that you wait for several seconds before it opens.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Windows Forms? If there is the possibility of switching to WPF, or at least hosting the WPF datagrid in a Windows Forms application (using [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx)).

WPF can utilize virtualization and allows more items without lagging (because it does not look at items that aren't rendered, pretty much like you suggested).

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows Forms. I can't switch to WPF because it's a large project with 10 years of development behind.